# MySQL combine two columns and add into a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following structure with a MySQL table:

```
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    zipcode     |      city      |   state  |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|     10954      |     Nanuet     |    NY    |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
```

I want to combine the above 3 columns into one column like this:

```
+---------------------+
|      combined       |
+---------------------+
| 10954 - Nanuet, NY  |
+---------------------+
```

And I want to add this "combined" column to the end of the table without destroying the original 3 fields.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Create the column:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN combined VARCHAR(50);
```

Update the current values:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET combined = CONCAT(zipcode, ' - ', city, ', ', state);
```

Update all future values automatically:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.combined = CONCAT(new.zipcode, ' - ', new.city, ', ', new.state);

CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.combined = CONCAT(new.zipcode, ' - ', new.city, ', ', new.state);
```

Comment: How do I set two fields on a update, I tried adding another set new.rowname statement but just get an error.

Comment: I'm going from memory here, but I'm pretty sure you can just separate the values to set by commas like: set new.foo = 1, new.bar = 2

Comment: I was wondering what if one field is to come from a different table, i.e. city coming from table2??

Comment: You can query another table in a subquery from a trigger, something like `set newLearn more….combined = (select city from foo where ...)`. However, you should use great caution when building dependencies across tables in triggers. This can cause some really nasty locking issues because any update to one table may require locking multiple other tables. In most cases, you can find a better way, perhaps by either normalizing the data structure better or pushing some of the logic up into your application code rather than pushing it down into the database.

Comment: In most cases, it seems more optimal to `concat` the data on the fly, rather than creating a new column instance. See MikeTheReader's answer.

Comment: it won't have a maximum of 50 chars? What will happen if the concat have more than 50 chars?

Answer (score 27):

Are you sure you want to do this? In essence, you're duplicating the data that is in the three original columns. From that point on, you'll need to make sure that the data in the combined field matches the data in the first three columns. This is more overhead for your application, and other processes that update the system will need to understand the relationship.

If you need the data, why not select in when you need it? The SQL for selecting what would be in that field would be:

```
SELECT CONCAT(zipcode, ' - ', city, ', ', state) FROM Table;
```

This way, if the data in the fields changes, you don't have to update your combined field.

Comment: I'm using an AutoComplete function and I want to be able to search AutoComplete with both zipcode and city, this seems like the only easy way. At least, with my level of knowledge.

Comment: Do your autocomplete like: **SELECT * from table where zipcode LIKE '%q% OR city LIKE '%q% or state LIKE '%q%**

Comment: This feels the cleanest to me. Duplicating data and then having to check they're in sync, and instituting additional logic to solve out-of-sync issues in higher-level code seems much dirtier than simply concatenating upon `SELECT` or even better using the app to concat it. Couldn't agree more with this answer, though @squawknull's answer introduced a cool concept, where appropriate.

Answer (score 16):

Add new column to your table and perfrom the query:

```
UPDATE tbl SET combined = CONCAT(zipcode, ' - ', city, ', ', state)
```

Comment: I like this option because it's performance over storage. For storage over performance, you could add the concat to the select query itself. See squaknull's post for the trigger code.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONCAT (zipcode, ' - ', city, ', ', state) AS COMBINED FROM TABLE