# How to delete old column after merging two in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was looking for an answer on how to combine two columns into a new one and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774532/mysql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-new-column) to be the perfect answer. However, since I really have NO experience with MySQL I was wondering how I would delete the old columns, too, when the table is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop columns (multiple) after merging it you can use the following Syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE table_Name DROP COLUMN columnName1, DROP COLUMN columnName2;
```

See [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP COLUMN columnName
```

Answer (score 1):

you can alter the table to drop the column. the syntax for that is

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN yourColumn
```