# Replace the content of an entire column in MYSQL by the content of two other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got three columns in a table: Login, Name and Familyname.

I want to replace everything in the column Login by the content of Name and Familyname.

Example:

- Login: janvdv
- Name :Jan
- Familyname: Vandevoorde

I want Login to be "Jan Vandevoorde".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774532/mysql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-new-column?rq=1.. See this question.. Use the trigger method stated in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table SET login = CONCAT_WS(' ', name, familyname);
```