# Construct a geometry type from two numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, casting, postgis

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774532/mysql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-new-column)

I want to make a third column from two of my existing columns. Say my current table (coords) looks like this:

```
(table: coords)
+----------------+------+
|    x     |     y      |
+----------------+------+
|     1    |     0      |
+----------------+------+
|     1    |     1      |
+----------------+------+
```

I want to make a third column of type geometry (from [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch06.html)) from the other two and add this column to that table. The final table should look like:

```
(table: pointsT)
+-----+----------+------+----+-----
|     x    |     y      |  coord  |
+----------------+------+----------
|     1    |     0      |  (1, 0) |
+----------------+------+----------
|     1    |     1      |  (1, 1) |
+----------------+------+----------
```

I want to create a table from this. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE pointsT(x text, y text, point geometry);

INSERT INTO points(x, y, point)
SELECT CO.x, CO.y, CO.'POINT(CO.x CO.y)' AS p FROM coords AS CO;
```

**Edit: From Edwins Answer**
Using Edwins answer, this would be the full command:

```
CREATE TABLE pointsT(x text, y text, point geometry);

INSERT INTO points(x, y, point)
SELECT CO.x, CO.y, ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(CO.x CO.y), 4326) AS wgs84long_la FROM coords AS CO;
```

Comment: If you really intend to create a *table* holding these three columns, don't. Store `x` and `y` or store the `point`, but not both.

Comment: Good point. This is actually just an example I made up to understand what I'm doing for my real table. Also, trying to emphasize that I need point of type geometry

Comment: There are [different techniques shown here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58605/which-function-for-creating-a-point-in-postgis/58630#58630)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `point`

- There is no such thing as "Postgre GIS", you mean [PostGis](http://postgis.net/).
- [`point`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6542) is a regular type of standard PostgreSQL. You don't need PostGis for that, but it's used a lot in PostGis, too, of course.
- The simplest and most effective way to create a point from two numbers is the [`point()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE). It takes two `double precision` numbers, but will accept `integer` or `numeric` just as well:

```
SELECT *, point(x,y) AS coord FROM tbl;
```

#### `geometry`

To build a PostGis `geometry` type you need to define an [`SRID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID) additionally, which identifies the spacial reference system. There are several [geometry constructors](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors) available. Since you start from two numeric columns I suggest:

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x, y), 4326) As wgs84long_lat;
```

Be sure not to confuse longitude and latitude. [More details in the manual.](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_SetSRID.html)

Comment: Edited for clarity. I meant the geometry type in PostGis

Comment: Perhaps something like:
SELECT CO.x, CO.y, geometry('POINT(CO.x CO.y)') AS p FROM coords AS CO;

Comment: @smaccoun: Consider the addition for a `geometry` type.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT x, y, '(' || x || ',' || y || ')' AS coord
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Does not seem to recognize the double quotes here, or possibly the + sign (error: column "(" + x + "," + y + ")" does not exist)

Comment: oops my bad not enough sleep

Comment: You are concatenating a *string literal*, which is not a `column of type POINT`, yet. You would have to cast: `('(' || x || ',' || y || ')')::point`, but there is a simpler route to that destination ...

Comment: Indeed. I have also edited for clarity, looking for POINT of type geometry from PostGIS