# I want to put 'given' and 'surname' column together into 'fullname' in SQL, how would i go about in doing so. tnx

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I currently have them separated but would prefer to have both together in one column.

Comment: If you want to do this in a select statement, use one of the answers below.  To permanently change your table, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774532/mysql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-a-new-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(given, ' ', surname) AS fullname FROM tablename
```

or for null safe,

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', given, surname)  AS fullname FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate them using:

```
select CONCAT(given,' ',surname) as fullname;
```