# Cannot add MySql auto-generated column with AS keyword

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table in MySQL with an auto-generated column.
I am following the syntax of the user guide:
[User guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)
At the very bottom of the page they are doing exactly the same as me

This what I am typing :

```
create table Player (
    firstName varchar(255),
    lastName varchar(255),
    fullName varchar(255) as (CONCAT( firstName, lastName ))
);
```

This is the error message :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as (CONCAT( firstName, lastName ))
>       )' at line 4

Comment: can you put your query here?

Comment: SELECT VERSION;

Comment: Concat in creation is not possible. Do it in select query while you fetching data from player table.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774532/mysql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-a-new-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774532/mysql-combine-two-columns-and-add-into-a-new-column) I found a post regarding this same issue. Please refer I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: @SumeshTG Concat should be possible when creating a table, since it its written in official documentation (look at the very bottom) : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html. I do not want to do it at select time, I want the column auto-generated upon insertion.

Comment: @LongLuong no, this not a bracket issue

Comment: @bretondev Ok .It is mysql 5.7 , check your version

Answer (score 1):

What is your MySQL version? Generated columns were added in **MySQL 5.7.5**. My first guess would be that you are using an older version. You can check by executing the following query: `SELECT version();`

Comment: the version is MySQL 5.6.37

Comment: so that's why it's not working. you need to update to at least 5.7.5 for generated columns.